# how to take particular the value from the list

Tags: python

```
s = [(Decimal('1655275144000'),)]
```

I need to take only the '1655275144000' in a variable

I have the below error when I call `s[0]`, how do I get around it?

[image]

Comment: You need to import the decimal class first

Comment: The error tells you the issue, which comes when running `s = [(Decimal('1655275144000'),)],` not `s[0]`

Comment: from decimal import Decimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import class Decimal :

```
from decimal import Decimal
```

And then, your value is inside a tuple, inside and array, so in order to access it :

```
s[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This error show you forgot to import the Decimal module.
Just add this to the top of your file:

`from decimal import Decimal`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import Decimal before getting decimals in that list. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the import for the Decimal you are using. Do this:

```
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal

s = [(Decimal('1655275144000'),)]
```